# api that gives all needed pieces for a car from its vin number

Tags: api, vin

I'm developing an application and I'm looking for an api that gives all car parts  from its vin number

I know it's not going to be for free and it's ok
any suggestions please ? thank you

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by `all suitable pieces`? Are you sure this is a specific programming question?

Comment: Thanks for your question, I mean car parts from vin number

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need it but in my project I used the [United States Department of Transportation's API](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/). It gives informations about the car and it's free to use.

It's more centered around American's Specifications, but there is also a call for Canadian Specifications.

You can also choose the data format you want between XML, CSV and JSON !